# Append not available from unity to xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode7, unity-game-engine, xcode7.3

So i have an x-code project, which i use as my template for a unity app. 
I have made some (small) changes to the x-code environment (post build), and always used the append option when building from unity, so i won't have to create a new x-code project folder, and do these changes for each build.

A few days ago i upgraded the OS AND x-code 7.3.1.

Now the append option is no longer available.

Anyone know a solution for this?

I tried building to another location with no luck.